# Efficiency of storing information on dom or make simple mongodb query?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a linked-list, I was thinking of storing the parent's information on the dom but that would clutter the html a tad-bit, however I could also do a simple mongodb call to get the information. I know this is a marginal computational resource difference and storing the information on the dom would probably be more efficient, the best inference I can make about mongodb is that because we already have subscribed that information, we have access to it and making a mongodb query takes little resource.

I suppose at the end of the day, which approach is better?

Comment: Interesting problem, but we'd need more details to help. The legendary Jon Skeet wrote on [How to ask the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) - you can start by getting a username :)

Answer (score 0):

Its may be better to take it from Mongodb, because you're sure you have the latest data and you wont need additional code for updating the dom.

The concept in Meteor is that your DOM can have a data context that you can use to find the mongodb data very easily without having to store anything in the DOM. This concept removes the need to store data within DOM elements.

for example you could have

HTML

```
{{#with data}}
    My Dom
{{/with}}
```

Template

```
Template.mytemplate.data = function() {
    return { data: xx}
}
```

This way you can have dynamic/reactive data without necessarily having to update the DOM.

With the new Meteor UI (Blaze release) set for 0.8.0 you could even pass down data to your template

```
{{>mytemplate okenabled=false}}
```